# Training RL-Agent for Gym-Pong on EC2 Ubuntu leads to OOM

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-ec2, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to run a script on a g4dn.xlarge ec2 instance on aws, but appx. after 17 episodes the instance is running into oom. I can see how usage of RAM is increasing until 16 GB is full, after that the instance becomes unresponsive.

Does anybody have an idea how to prevent this. This would be the code i am using at the moment:

```
import gym
from ale_py import ALEInterface
import numpy as np
import cv2
import random
from collections import deque
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import requests
import logging
import psutil
import os
import time
import gc
import tracemalloc
from memory_profiler import profile
from gpustat import GPUStatCollection
import subprocess


# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='output.log', filemode='w')

# Constants
STATE_SIZE = (64, 64, 4)  # Preprocessed image dimensions
ACTION_SIZE = 3  # Number of actions (up, down, no movement)
BATCH_SIZE = 16
MEMORY_SIZE = 5000
TRAIN_START = 1000
GAMMA = 0.99
EPSILON_START = 1.0
EPSILON_MIN = 0.1
EPSILON_DECAY = 0.995
LEARNING_RATE = 0.00025

# Function to send Telegram message
def send_telegram_message(bot_token, chat_id, message):
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendMessage"
    payload = {"chat_id": chat_id, "text": message}
    requests.post(url, data=payload)

# Frame preprocessing
def preprocess(state):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(state, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    cropped = gray[34:194, :]
    resized = cv2.resize(cropped, (64, 64), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return resized

# DQN architecture
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (8, 8), strides=(4, 4), activation='relu', input_shape=STATE_SIZE))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(ACTION_SIZE))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE))
    return model

# Agent memory and experience replay
class Memory:
    def __init__(self, max_size):
        self.buffer = deque(maxlen=max_size)

    def add(self, experience):
        self.buffer.append(experience)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.buffer, batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.buffer)
    
def log_gpu_usage():
    gpu_stats = subprocess.check_output("nvidia-smi", shell=True)
    logging.debug("GPU Usage:\n" + gpu_stats.decode("utf-8"))
    

@profile    
def train_one_episode(env, model, memory, epsilon, episode, episodes):
    start_time = time.time()  # Start time
    state, _ = env.reset()  # Extract the image data and ignore the metadata
    state = preprocess(state)
    state = np.stack([state] * 4, axis=2)
    done = False
    total_reward = 0

    while not done:
        action = np.argmax(model.predict(np.expand_dims(state, axis=0))[0])

        if np.random.rand() <= epsilon:
            action = random.randrange(ACTION_SIZE)

        step_result = env.step(action + 3 if action > 0 else action)
        if len(step_result) == 4:
            next_state, reward, _ , done, _ = step_result
        elif len(step_result) == 5:  # Some wrappers might return an extra value
            next_state, reward, done, _, _ = step_result
        else:
            raise ValueError
            
        next_state = preprocess(next_state)
        next_state = np.append(state[:, :, 1:], np.expand_dims(next_state, axis=2), axis=2)

        memory.add((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

        total_reward += reward
        state = next_state

        if len(memory) >= TRAIN_START:
            mini_batch = memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
            states = np.array([sample[0] for sample in mini_batch])
            actions = np.array([sample[1] for sample in mini_batch])
            rewards = np.array([sample[2] for sample in mini_batch])
            next_states = np.array([sample[3] for sample in mini_batch])
            dones = np.array([sample[4] for sample in mini_batch])

            target_q = model.predict(states)
            next_q = model.predict(next_states)

            for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
                if dones[i]:
                    target_q[i][actions[i]] = rewards[i]
                else:
                    target_q[i][actions[i]] = rewards[i] + GAMMA * np.amax(next_q[i])

            model.fit(states, target_q, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)

        # Decaying epsilon
        if epsilon > EPSILON_MIN:
            epsilon *= EPSILON_DECAY
        else:
            epsilon = EPSILON_MIN

    return total_reward, epsilon
                                      
def train_dqn(env, episodes=300):
    memory = Memory(MEMORY_SIZE)
    epsilon = EPSILON_START
    model = create_model()

    for episode in range(episodes):
        # Log GPU utilization
        log_gpu_usage()
        total_reward, epsilon = train_one_episode(env, model, memory, epsilon, episode, episodes)
        logging.debug(f"Episode {episode + 1}/{episodes}, total reward: {total_reward}")
        logging.info("Episode: {}, Replay Buffer Size: {}".format(episode, len(memory.buffer)))

        # Send Telegram message after each episode
        send_telegram_message(
            bot_token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            chat_id="XXXXXXX",
            message=f"Episode {episode + 1}/{episodes}, total reward: {total_reward}"
        )

    # Save the trained model
    model.save("pong_dqn.h5")

# Play the game using the trained DQN agent
def play_dqn(env, model_path, episodes=5):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

    for episode in range(episodes):
        state = env.reset()
        state = preprocess(state)
        state = np.stack([state] * 4, axis=2)
        done = False
        total_reward = 0

        while not done:
            env.render()
            action = np.argmax(model.predict(np.expand_dims(state, axis=0))[0])
            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action + 1)
            next_state = preprocess(next_state)
            next_state = np.append(state[:, :, 1:], np.expand_dims(next_state, axis=2), axis=2)
            total_reward += reward
            state = next_state

        print(f"Episode {episode + 1}/{episodes}, total reward: {total_reward}")

    env.close()
    
# Load the environment
env = gym.make('ALE/Pong-v5')

# Train the DQN agent
train_dqn(env)
```

And this would be an excerpt from the memory analyzer:

```
    76  11691.1 MiB  11691.1 MiB           1   @profile    
    78  11691.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       start_time = time.time()  # Start time
    79  11691.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       state, _ = env.reset()  # Extract the image data and ignore the metadata
    80  11691.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       state = preprocess(state)
    81  11691.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       state = np.stack([state] * 4, axis=2)
    82  11691.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       done = False
    83  11691.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       total_reward = 0
    86  11691.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       tracemalloc.start()
    88  12347.2 MiB    -22.5 MiB         765       while not done:
    89  12346.8 MiB    120.4 MiB         764           action = np.argmax(model.predict(np.expand_dims(state, axis=0))[0])
    91  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764           if np.random.rand() <= epsilon:
    92  12332.3 MiB     -2.2 MiB          61               action = random.randrange(ACTION_SIZE)
    94  12346.8 MiB    -20.9 MiB         764           step_result = env.step(action + 3 if action > 0 else action)
    95  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764           if len(step_result) == 4:
    97  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764           elif len(step_result) == 5:  # Some wrappers might return an extra value
    98  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764               next_state, reward, done, _, _ = step_result
   102  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764           next_state = preprocess(next_state)
   103  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764           next_state = np.append(state[:, :, 1:], np.expand_dims(next_state, axis=2), axis=2)
   105  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764           memory.add((state, action, reward, next_state, done))
   107  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764           total_reward += reward
   108  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764           state = next_state
   110  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764           if len(memory) >= TRAIN_START:
   111  12346.8 MiB    -22.8 MiB         764               mini_batch = memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
   112  12347.0 MiB   -311.1 MiB       14516               states = np.array([sample[0] for sample in mini_batch])
   113  12347.0 MiB   -431.9 MiB       14516               actions = np.array([sample[1] for sample in mini_batch])
   114  12347.0 MiB   -431.9 MiB       14516               rewards = np.array([sample[2] for sample in mini_batch])
   115  12347.0 MiB   -431.9 MiB       14516               next_states = np.array([sample[3] for sample in mini_batch])
   116  12347.0 MiB   -431.9 MiB       14516               dones = np.array([sample[4] for sample in mini_batch])
   118  12347.1 MiB     82.8 MiB         764               target_q = model.predict(states)
   119  12347.1 MiB    126.7 MiB         764               next_q = model.predict(next_states)
   121  12347.1 MiB   -347.7 MiB       12988               for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
   122  12347.1 MiB   -327.6 MiB       12224                   if dones[i]:
   123  12288.5 MiB     -0.4 MiB          15                       target_q[i][actions[i]] = rewards[i]
   125  12347.1 MiB   -327.2 MiB       12209                       target_q[i][actions[i]] = rewards[i] + GAMMA * np.amax(next_q[i])
   127  12347.2 MiB    114.0 MiB         764               model.fit(states, target_q, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=0)
   130  12347.2 MiB    -22.5 MiB         764           if epsilon > EPSILON_MIN:
   133  12347.2 MiB    -22.5 MiB         764               epsilon = EPSILON_MIN
   135  12347.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       end_time = time.time()  # End time
   138  12353.9 MiB      6.7 MiB           1       snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
   141  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       tracemalloc.stop()
   144  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')
   146  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       logging.debug("[ Top 10 ]")
   147  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB          11       for stat in top_stats[:10]:
   148  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB          10           logging.debug(str(stat))
   151  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
   152  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       mem_info = process.memory_info()
   153  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       rss_memory = mem_info.rss / (1024 ** 2)  # in MB
   155  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       logging.debug(f"Episode {episode + 1}/{episodes}, total reward: {total_reward}, time taken: {end_time - start_time} seconds")
   156  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       logging.info("Episode: {}, Replay Buffer Size: {}".format(episode, len(memory.buffer)))
   157  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       logging.info(f"Memory usage: {rss_memory} MB")
   160  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           2       send_telegram_message(
   161  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           bot_token="5998256243:AAFyERawwx5neWl6DTeof7Ui8fvSsrC_qU8",
   162  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           chat_id="33223676",
   163  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           message=f"Episode {episode + 1}/{episodes}, total reward: {total_reward}"
   167  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
   169  12353.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return epsilon
```

You can see that there is always a big jump in memory usage in the while not done:-line of code.

Does anybody have experience with this? Is the solution just to get a bigger ec2-instance with more RAM and GPU? This is just a simple pong-game to learn, so i assumed that a g4dn.xlarge instance must have been more than enough.